# What is the reason for very high variations in val accuracy for multiple model runs?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, training-data, genome

I have a 2 layered Neural Network that I'm training on about 10000 features (genomic data) with about 100 samples in my data set. Now I realized that anytime I run my model (i.e. compile & fit) I get varying validation/testing accuracys even if I leave the train/test/validation split untouched. Sometimes its around 70% sometimes around 90%.

Due to the stochastic nature of the NN I anticipate some variation but could these strong fluctuations be a sign of something else?

Comment: Does this behaviour change, when you try different optimizers?

Comment: For how many epochs are you training your model? If only for a few, the variance you might be seeing could be due to random initialization. Another candidate is the learning rate of your optimizer. 100 samples is very few for a NN that will have tens of thousands of parameters. So you probably need to run it for something like 500 epochs with a relatively high learning rate (like 1e-2 or so) to see consistency across runs.

Comment: @MichaelJanz How exactly could the optimizer influence the variation in val acc? I have tried a few different optimizers but have found not difference. The validation acc fluctuates by at least +/-8.

Comment: @Addy Depending on the learning rate I tried different numbers on epochs to avoid training accuracy going up all the way to 100%. Less with high learning rates vice versa. I also had runs with 50 epochs but still saw fluctuations. 
If I try 500 with a high learning rate won't I terribly overfit the neural network? Or what do you mean?

Comment: Can you share the sizes of train/validation/test datasets? What is the size of your layers (those are Dense layers I suppose) and your output? Also, do you achieve consistent train accuracy?

Comment: Train/val/test is 64/17/21, I have a regular Sequential NN with 2 dense layers with each 12 neurons and a binary classifcation output. The training accuracy always reaches something between 98 and 100%

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you're seeing such a big instability with your validation accuracy is because your neural network is huge in comparison to the data you train it on.

Even with just 12 neurons per layer, you still have `12 * 10000 + 12 = 120012` parameters in your first layer. Now think about what the neural network does under the hood. It takes your 10000 inputs, it multiplies each input by some weight and then sums all these inputs. Now you provide it only 64 training examples on which the training algorithm is supposed to decide what are the correct input weights. Just based on intuition, from a purely combinatorial perspective there is going to be large amount of weight assignments that do well on your 64 training samples. And you have no guarantee that the training algorithm will pick such weight assignment that will also do well on your out-of-sample data.

Given neural network is able to represent a wide variety of functions (it's been proven that under certain assumptions it can approximate any function, that's called general approximation). To select the function you want you provide the training algorithm with data to constrain the space of all possible functions the network can represent to a subspace of functions that fit your data. However, such function is in no way guaranteed to represent the true underlying relationship between the input and the output. And especially if the number of parameters is larger than the number of samples (in this case by a few orders of magnitude), you're nearly guaranteed to see your network simply memorize the samples in your training data, simply because it has the capacity to do so and you haven't constrained it enough.

In other words, what you're seeing is overfitting. In NNs, the general rule of thumb is that you want at least a couple of times more samples than you have parameters (look in to the Hoeffding Inequality for theoretical rationale of this) and in effect the more samples you have, the less you're afraid of overfitting.

So here is a couple of possible solutions:

1. Use an algorithm that's more suitable for the case where you have high input dimension and low sample count, such as Kernel SVM (Support Vector Machine). With such a low sample count, it's quite possible that a Kernel SVM algorithm will achieve better and more consistent validation accuracy. (You can easily test this, they are available in the scikit-learn package, really easy to use)
2. If you insist on using NN - use regularization. Given the fact you already have working code, this will be easy, just add kernel_regularizer to all your layers, I would try both L1 and L2 regularization (probably separately). L1 regularization tends to push weights to zero so it might help reduce the number of parameters in your problem. L2 just tries to make all the weights small. Use your validation set to decide the best value for each regularization. You can optimize both for the best mean accuracy and also the lowest variance in accuracy on your validation data (do something like 20 training runs for each parameter value of L1 and L2 regularization, usually just trying different orders of magnitude is sufficient, e.g. 1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 1e1).
3. If most of your input features are not really predictive or if they are highly correlated, PCA (Principal Component Analysis) can be used to project your inputs into a much lower dimensional space (e.g. from 10000 to 20), where you'd have much smaller neural network (still I'd use L1 or L2 for regularization because even then you'd have more weights than training samples)

On a final note, the point of a testing set is to use it very sparsely (ideally only once). It should be the final reported metric after all your research and model tuning is done. You should not optimize any values on it. You should do all this on your validation set. To avoid overfitting on your validation set, look into k-fold cross validation.

Comment: quality answer here

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate answer & explanation!! I actually do need a NN. Unfortunately I had already tried PCA and got worse training accuracies with not change in the variations of validation accuracies. 
Just tried Regularization but that also did noch bring any real improvement.
When I do k fold crossvalidation to avoid overfitting on val data, I observed that the vadliation accuracy in the first fold is always by far the lowest (like 30% vs avg of 85% or even worse). Might you have an idea what that could be due to?

Comment: It's because you have very little data in each split, I would expect to see such wild variations in validation accuracy, so it's okay. When you say you tried Regularization and it did not help, what do you mean by that? What have you tried exactly? I would increase the regularization constants basically until I'd see similar accuracy on training and on validation data. As long as you see 100% on your training set, you can be pretty sure you're overfitting (if the data is real world data, not synthetic).

Comment: Actually there was an issue with my data not being shuffled. 
But I still see quite big variations. With 20 fold cross validation I get a mean validation accuracy over all folds of 81% +/- 17% for the base model. I tried l1 and l2 for penalties from 1 to 0,00001 and even tried combining l2 with dropout layers but I either get similar or worse validation accuracies. The fluctuations/dev reaching from  +/-11% to +/-22%. With fluctuations of the +/- dev even between multiple cross validation runs of the same parameter configuration.

Comment: As I said, the variations you are seeing are in line with the number of samples, I'd expect such result. By 20 runs I did not mean 20-fold CV, but rather e.g. a 4-fold CV run 20 times. 20-fold CV is unreasonable, because if you have 81 training samples, this would mean you have 2 samples in each validation split, that's just too few. Just think for a second what are you actually measuring and on how few samples, of course the metrics will be noisy.
Can you report your batch size, epoch count, optimizer and learning rate? In fact can you post your training script?